# Discrete Random Variable's PMF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a discrete random variable, X, that has a probability mean function defined as f(x) = c(2/3)^x for all x = 0, 1, 2...

I'm trying to find the value for c to make this a pmf. There is apparently a value for c, but the summation of (2/3)^x from 0 to infinity seems infinite to me, which makes me think it's impossible for this to be a pmf...

What am I missing here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The sum is finite:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} r^k = \frac{1}{1-r}$$

when $|r| \lt 1$.  Here, $r=2/3$, so you get

$$c \frac{1}{1-(2/3)} = 1 \implies c = \frac13$$